# Why does a "Extract Here" context menu work incorrectly?

Tags: extract

I'm a beginner in Linux.

I extracted a android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86.tar.bz2 in Downloads directory with a "Extract Here" context menu.

And I executed "ndk-build" command. Then I got an error message like below.

> ndk-build arm-linux-androideabi.gcc : Command not found.

I found that file doesn't exist.

So, I extract manually in a terminal like below.

```
tar -xvjf android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86.tar.bz2.
```

Now, it works correctly, because arm-linux-androideabi.gcc file is correctly extracted.

Why does that difference occur?

Does a "Extract Here" context menu do invalid action, or do I misuse the tool?

---

Thanks for your answer, jackweirdy, Eliah Kagan.

But my problem is not about the path.

For example, "Extract Here" doesn't make a arm-linux-adnroideabi.gcc file. But "tar" make a arm-linux-androideabi.gcc file.

When I used "Extract Here", it extracted below files in the directory.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line
arm-linux-androideabi-c++filt
arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-elfedit
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.6.x-google
arm-linux-androideabi-gcov
arm-linux-androideabi-gdb
arm-linux-androideabi-gdbtui
arm-linux-androideabi-gprof
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf
arm-linux-androideabi-run
arm-linux-androideabi-size
arm-linux-androideabi-strings
```

But when I used "tar", it extracted below files in the directory.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line
arm-linux-androideabi-ar
arm-linux-androideabi-as
arm-linux-androideabi-c++
arm-linux-androideabi-c++filt
arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-elfedit
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.6.x-google
arm-linux-androideabi-gcov
arm-linux-androideabi-gdb
arm-linux-androideabi-gdbtui
arm-linux-androideabi-gprof
arm-linux-androideabi-ld
arm-linux-androideabi-ld.bfd
arm-linux-androideabi-ld.gold
arm-linux-androideabi-nm
arm-linux-androideabi-objcopy
arm-linux-androideabi-objdump
arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf
arm-linux-androideabi-run
arm-linux-androideabi-size
arm-linux-androideabi-strings
arm-linux-androideabi-strip
```

I can't understand why "Extract Here" can not extract all files.

Comment: The error `ndk-build arm-linux-androideabi.gcc : Command not found.` means you tried to run a command like `"ndk-build arm-linux-androideabi.gcc"`, `'ndk-build arm-linux-androideabi.gcc'`, or `ndk-build\ arm-linux-androideabi.gcc`. If the spaces between words in a command are quoted (either by being contained in actual quotes, or being preceded by a backslash character), then the space will be taken as a letter in the command rather than as a separator. I'm not sure what `ndk-build` command you ran or how you ran it, but if you're running it manually you should do it *without* any quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Extract Here moves the files and folders of an archive into a new folder with the same name as the archive, for example, consider this archive:

```
archive.tar.gz:
 - foo/
    - foo1.png
    - foo2.jpg
 - bar.xml
```

"Extract Here" will create a new folder called "archive" and put `foo`, its contents and `bar.xml` within the archive folder, whereas running the `tar` command you posted would put those files in the current directory.